# What are some resources for learning mathematical writing?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, proof-writing, mathematical-modeling, online-resources

I'm looking for recommendations for some resources which will teach me how to convey ideas through consistent mathematical writing?

For example, the book [mathematical thinking and writing](https://www.elsevier.com/books/mathematical-thinking-and-writing/maddox/978-0-08-049647-4) is one resource teaches ways to do that. Is there any other good YouTube series? Online resource?

I'm mainly looking forward to improve ideas in a more general and abstract mathematical language, involving creating and specifying sets, functions and their spaces, operations on such functions, specifying proofs etc.

Comment: Practice. Watching videos and reading books about how to write proofs won't make you better at it, just like you don't learn how to write papers by reading articles in journals.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX

Answer (score 2):

Franco Vivaldi : Mathematical Writing (Springer Undergraduate Mathematics Series)

https://www.math.uh.edu/~tomforde/MathWriting.pdf

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.04888.pdf

Comment: 404 to first URL